# Build a dataset based on an exponential distribution

Tags: r, simulation, exponential

I'm trying to simulate a dataset based on simulated data of an exponential distribution with lambda = 0.0002. From this simulation I need to complete a spreadsheet with 30 columns that takes into account an initial value and the calculated values ​​of the previous column. I'm not sure how to program the loop or rbind to simulate the data. The attached image shows how the logic to be followed. The initial values ​​(Q0) are used only in the first column. The data for all columns must be in the range Q0-Qmax (values ​​above or below these should be limited to these values).

[image: Attached image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called R-commander that can help you to produce a simulated data set based on an exponential distribution.

```
install.packages(Rcmdr)
library(Rcmdr)                                                                 
# note: sometimes library(Rcmdr) does not open the R-commander window. If this happens use require(Rcmdr)
```

This will open a new R-commander window. Then on the top bar click on Distributions -> Continuous Distributions -> Exponential Distribution -> Sample from Exponential Distribution. Simply specify the requirements you need for the simulation, and the R-commander will automatically generate the syntax for your simulated data set. Copy and then paste that syntax into RStudio.